# Can bindable decorator on the custom attribute be locked to be only oneWay or oneTime?

Tags: aurelia

I know that one can declare attribute with defaultBindingMode like this

```
@bindable({ defaultBindingMode: bindingMode.oneTime }) maxSize: number;
```

but can it be declared so that user of it cannot specify any other mode?

Comment: I don't think there's a way to lock a binding mode... but why would you ever want to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't possible, and would go against the "Conventions are great until you need to override them" ethos of Aurelia. You are specifying a convention for your component by specifying the default binding mode.

That being said, you could force a one-time binding inside your own control and effectively force a one-time binding on any consumers of your control.

For example, in a custom attribute, do everything you want your attribute to do in the `bind` callback and don't set up any "Changed" callbacks. Or in a custom element, use the `one-time` binding command for all data-binding in your component's view.

Comment: That is what I ended up doing. Out of about 15 "bindings" only 3 are observable all other are just settings as far as how component looks, and are not changable. So I ended up only hooking at 3 "changed" callbacks.